# No more Global.asax, but OWIN Startup.cs

Tags: rest, owin, global-asax

So someone decided global.asax was no longer needed and we should all use OWIN.  This is new to me and all the examples I have found so far would make me extremely proficient in displaying "hello world" everywhere.  Nice as this is it isnt exactly useful.

Our existing REST APIs all use a global.asax file.  It seems I now need to migrate this accross.  Below is the contents of our Application_Start() method :

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {

        SD.Tools.OrmProfiler.Interceptor.InterceptorCore.Initialize("UnityWebService");
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo(String.Format("{0}/{1}", System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, "log4net.config")));
        UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();
        AutoMapperConfig.Configure();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new ExceptionHandlingAttribute());
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new ValidateModelStateAttribute());
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new CheckModelForNullAttribute());
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new MessageHandlerMain());
    }
```

How do I convert that so it would work in startup.cs?  Is it just a straight transpose accross into :

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

    }
```

Am I missing a trick?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move most of these lines unmodified into the `Configuration` method of your `Startup` class. Something like the following should do it:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    config.Filters.Add(new ExceptionHandlingAttribute());
    // move other lines over here
    appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir.  your help is greatly appreciated